# Looking for a tool that can return SPs doing a DML on a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on a big application on SQL Server 2008 with 60 000 stored procedures and over 10 000 tables. Is there a tool through which I can do impact analysis to find out all SPs doing a DML on a table?

Answer (score 4):

Try out [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm), by Red Gate (it's free).

Comment: +1 yes, absolutely wonderful tool, and even more wonderful that it's free!

Answer (score 2):

The following SP will allow you to search for a Keyword (e.g. INSERT) and return all of the Objects where the Keyword exists within your database, giving:

- Object name
- Object type
- Useful command to see Object text

Due to technical difficulties with the Code block, I've had to split it up.  But, create a new Stored Procedure, add 2 parameters:

```
@SearchStr varchar(100),
@RowsReturned int = NULL    OUT
```

And then paste in the following below:

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT USER_NAME(o.uid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(c.id) AS 'Object name',
        CASE 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsReplProc') = 1 
                THEN 'Replication stored procedure'
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsExtendedProc') = 1 
                THEN 'Extended stored procedure'        
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
                THEN 'Stored Procedure' 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTrigger') = 1 
                THEN 'Trigger' 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTableFunction') = 1 
                THEN 'Table-valued function' 
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsScalarFunction') = 1 
                THEN 'Scalar-valued function'
            WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsInlineFunction') = 1 
                THEN 'Inline function'  
        END AS 'Object type',
        'EXEC sp_helptext ''' + USER_NAME(o.uid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(c.id) + '''' AS 'Run this command to see the object text'
    FROM    syscomments c
        INNER JOIN
        sysobjects o
        ON c.id = o.id
    WHERE   c.text LIKE '%' + @SearchStr + '%'  AND
        encrypted = 0               AND
        (
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsReplProc') = 1      OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsExtendedProc') = 1  OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsProcedure') = 1     OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTrigger') = 1       OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsTableFunction') = 1 OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsScalarFunction') = 1    OR
        OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id, 'IsInlineFunction') = 1    
        )
    ORDER BY    'Object type', 'Object name'
    SET @RowsReturned = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Answer (score 2):

or this one [SQLDog](http://www.sqldog.com/EN/features.html)...also Free

Answer (score 0):

There is another [free tool](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) for this from ApexSQL. And nice "how to" article on their blog

http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/quickly-search-for-sql-database-data-and-objects/